# Security Error with <object> tag in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, security, object, typescript

I am adding new HMTL pages with  tag.

```
<object *ngIf='displayUrl' resize-to-tile type="text/html" 
        [attr.data]="displayUrl" >
</object>



  this.displayUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.parameters.items.data.params.items[0].value);
```

But I have next error:

> SafeValue must use [property]=binding: undefined (see
>   http://g.co/ng/security#xss) SafeValue must use [property]=binding:
>   undefined (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `attr.`

```
[data]="displayUrl" >
```

The value returned from `bypassSecurityXxx` is wrapped in a class.
Attribute binding only supports string values, therefore `[attr.xxx]` breaks sanitization.

The `<object>` element has a `data` property, therefore `attr.` isn't required anyway https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement